# Laravel Nested relationships using dot syntax querying each level

Tags: php, laravel, nested, eloquent

the goal here is to have my menu model create a tree with each related child and the child's related Page.

I'm generating a tree with my model like this...

```
 public static function tree()
{
    return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')))->with('Pages')->where('parent_id', '=', 0)->get();
}
```

But the problem comes with getting each childs related Page. 
I've tried this...

```
    return static::with([implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')) => function($query) {
        $query->with('Pages');
    }])->with('Pages')->where('parent_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

and adding the eager loading query didn't seem to work. i think maybe using the dot sytax and querying it only queries the last one? I'm not sure on that.

I need to query each level of the query but i don't know how.
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: it seems I've managed to fix this problem by doing this...

```
public static function genRelationalArray()
{
 $arr = [implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children'))];
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
      $item = 'children.Pages';
      $arr[] = $item;
      $item = 'children.'. $item;
    }
  return $arr;
}

public static function treeFromId($id)
{
  $childArr = static::genRelationalArray();
  return static::with($childArr)->with('Pages')->where('parent_id', '=', $id)->get();
}
```

but if there is a shorter more efficient way of doing this please post :)